# I have a proxied node app on port 9000 working well, but after login the port shows up why?

Tags: angularjs, express, nginx

My angular-fullstack express app is working well.  It is served on port 9000 through nginx using proxy_pass https://example.com:80 -> https://example.com:9000.  When a new user looks to https://example.com they are routed to https://example.com/login as expect.  However, once they login, whey see the url: https://example.com:9000 on firefox.  And on Chrome they see: https://example.com:9000/#  ??? why in the world is the port showing up and why is the # appearing?

In case the nginx settings are to blame for the proxy_pass, here they are:

```
  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $host;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; 
  }
```

Is there a simple way to tell nginx to hide the port on the response, and why does the # appear on Chrome?

Your insight is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are not redirecting your user in THAT specific address somehow in your code ? or like `redirect VAR_SITE_URL`from a config file ?

Comment: I hunted and no such luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the port number showing up, you might need to set the [`proxy_redirect` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) in your nginx config. As the linked doc states, `proxy_redirect`

> Sets the text that should be changed in the “Location” and “Refresh” header fields of a proxied server response

which is most likely where the port number is being added in.

As for the `#`, that's application specific - you're going to have to look at your code to figure out why.

Comment: I tried proxy_redirect https://example.com:9000/ https://example.com/ and a few variants, to no effect. So this is a puzzle!

Comment: Indeed. Can you use Firebug/Chrome Developer tools to watch what requests are made when you login?

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion.  This caused me to think a bit.... and I realized that on the passport side on google, I had the callback etc. pointed at example.com:9000.  So I fixed that and the port no longer shows up. Thanks for your suggestion. Now the only weirdness left is the /# that shows up and I don't have a clue where that is coming from yet.

Comment: Also, I think that the proxy_redirect helps a bit, in the case that I am not using passport for a plain login.

Comment: When does the #appear? In my experience when a # appears, it's because there's an <a> tag with href="#" set, and the user has clicked on said tag.

Comment: Thanks so much for the observation -- I am relatively certain that there may be such a link -- I will check and report back.

Comment: Dear kyl191 -- thanks SO MUCH for your suggestion.  This was indeed the issue!!!!